# Using JSON with jQuery form validation plugin

Tags: php, jquery, json

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="add" method="post" action="index.php">
            <input type="text" name="first">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value = "submit">
        </form>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/jqueryvalidation.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/globaltest.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#add').validate({

        rules: {

            first: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'login.php',
                datatype: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#add').serialize(),

                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);

                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$json = array(
    'name' => 'Bob'
);

echo json_encode($json);
```

When I use the jQuery form validation plugin , I noticed that when I submit the form and look at the console, I’m not getting back an object. This is what the output looks like:

[image]

However if i create a normal form without using the jQuery form validation plugin, i would get the expected output i'm looking for. I can clearly see that it is an object:

[image]

I'm not sure why there is a difference. Both the html and the PHP file are the same structure. What can i do to fix it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataType: "json"` tells jQuery to expect the response of the ajax request to be a json object.

But your PHP file does not return one, it's more than likely returning the content as `text/html` by default.

Add this header to your PHP file before you return the response:
`header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Incidentally, although the `dataType` property is not case-sensitive, it's good practice to use [camel-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for property names.